# Please, suggest a library to mock ajax requests in a browser

Tags: jquery, ajax, testing, mocking, stub

I've run into a problem with Ajax lately. I'm working on a frontend of a large application and at some point it calls a service which is being developed by another team. They have some hard performance issues and while they are doing they best t o keep it stable sometimes AJAX call times out or returns an error.

Meanwhile as I work on client-side I need to mock this service somehow. I could have just replace callback function with a modified version with some fake data I wonder if there are any more elegant ways to solve this problem.

I'd like to be able to the following:

- Completely stub the call to external service;
- Conditionally mock it: if it returns normally I prefer using the actual data, otherwise fake data is fine.
- Automatically actualize fake data: when a server call returns normally save the data behind the scenes so that it can be used for further executions in case of an error.
- Having an ability to pre-process the data coming to a server before it gets into a callback would also be quite nice.

I can certainly write something like that myself but I'm pretty sure that someone solved this problem already.

I'm using jQuery for AJAX calls so a jQuery-specific solution would work just fine, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**MockAjax** might be useful for you, take a look at:

[Mock Your Ajax Requests with Mockjax for Rapid Development](http://enterprisejquery.com/2010/07/mock-your-ajax-requests-with-mockjax-for-rapid-development/)

Answer (score 2):

[Deflect.io](http://www.deflect.io) allows your to seamlessly record and then replay requests made by your browser, and edit the responses if needed. All this without changing a single line of source code.

Disclaimer: I wrote Deflect.io O:)

Answer (score 1):

Well, for this purpose, I've been looking at test frameworks such as QUnit
http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit

..and perhaps you could use jQuery Mock Ajax?
https://github.com/appendto/jquery-mockjax

Answer (score 1):

This is a different approach to your problem. Maybe you could use tool like [**Fiddler**](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to create auto-response to your request. You can then easily see your request and define the response in the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

[Sinon.js](http://sinonjs.org) can do this through its fake [XMLHttpRequest](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#server) and its [fake server](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#fakeServer).